# Behaviour of precompiled header file causes error

Tags: c++, header-files

In below simple program,

```
#include<conio.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("print");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

gives error saying `1>e:\cust\a\a\a.cpp(14) : error C3861: 'getch': identifier not found`

I am using VS 2005. I know that "stdafx.h" is pre-compiled header, but why we should not add any header files before it?

Comment: You probably won't get any use out of precompiled headers for quite a while. And never any real use out of conio.h. stdio.h is deprecated.

Comment: Does it compile if you move the first `#include` after `stdafx.h`?

Comment: But if i add "conio.h" after "stdafx" it is not giving any error?

Comment: Yes. It is compiling! and no errors :)

Comment: Or move both `#include<conio.h>` and `#include<stdio.h>` into stdafx.h although for such a small program precompiled headers will not make much of a difference.

Comment: That is absolutely fine :) But why it is behaving like that?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` is supposed to be the first include in a cpp file.

Comment: Pay attention to the *warning* you get for this.  The compiler is telling you that it is skipping text to try to find stdafx.h

Comment: That's all the reason?

Comment: This is by design. And I agree with @HansPassant the compiler should have issued a warning about this.

Comment: @HansPassant Ya. I can see that. Thanks for your reply guys :)

Comment: I suggest you modify the build options and turn off all precompiled headers options and don't use `stdafx.h`.  When your projects are big enough where you are complaining about build time, then you may want to use precompiled headers.  Remember, if any of the headers in the precompiled headers is changed, everything gets rebuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precompiled headers in VS work in such a way that the precompiled header (normally named `stdafx.h`) has to be the first one in your includes. Even more, the line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

should be the first thing in your source, since MSDN says "The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled. It skips to just beyond the #include directive associated with the .h file, uses the code contained in the .pch file, and then compiles all code after filename. ".